# Why can't i use marked from "marked"

Tags: markdown, svelte, javascript-marked

For my Svelte project i want to use the function marked from the "marked" libary but i can't use the marked function. How do i fix this?

```
<script lang="ts">
</script>

<dialog bind:this={dialog} on:close={() => (showModal = false)} on:click|self={() => dialog.close()} >
<div class="label">Voeg de tekst in van je artikel</div>
<textarea bind:value={content} placeholder="Lange beschrijving" rows="20"/>
<div class="preview">{@html marked(content)}</div>
</dialog>
```

Comment: What does your `import` look like?

Comment: Potential duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/75178719/546730 ?

Comment: import marked from 'marked';

Comment: That should be in the code in the question, along with any errors/log output.