# Cannot import marked libary

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, svelte, javascript-marked

I want to import the Marked libary but it says: Cannot find module 'node_modules/marked/lib/marked.esm.js' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)

This is my Svelte code:

```
<script lang="ts">
import Parse from 'parse/dist/parse.min.js'
import { marked } from 'marked/lib/marked.esm.js';</script>
```

And this is my package.json:

```
{
"name": "name",
"version": "2.0.0",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "dev": "vite dev",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "test": "playwright test",
    "start": "node build",
    "check": "svelte-kit sync && svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json",
    "check:watch": "svelte-kit sync && svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json --watch",
    "lint": "prettier --plugin-search-dir . --check . && eslint .",
    "format": "prettier --plugin-search-dir . --write ."
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@playwright/test": "^1.28.1",
    "@sveltejs/adapter-auto": "^1.0.0",
    "@sveltejs/adapter-node": "^1.0.0",
    "@sveltejs/kit": "^1.24.1",
    "@types/marked": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/parse": "^3.0.5",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.45.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.45.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "eslint": "^8.28.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-svelte": "2.33.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.24",
    "postcss-load-config": "^4.0.1",
    "prettier": "^3.0.3",
    "prettier-plugin-svelte": "^3.0.3",
    "sass": "^1.57.0",
    "svelte": "^4.2.0",
    "svelte-check": "^3.5.1",
    "tslib": "^2.4.1",
    "typescript": "^5.2.0",
    "vite": "^4.0.0"
},
"type": "module",
"dependencies": {
    "d3-scale": "^4.0.2",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.7",
    "marked": "^9.1.2",
    "parse": "^3.5.1",
    "svelte-preprocess": "^5.0.4",
    "svelte-simple-modal": "^1.6.1",
    "svelte-tabs": "^1.1.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5"
},
"engines": {
    "node": "18.x",
    "npm": "9.x"
}
```

}

How can i solve this issue?

Comment: My import Parse from 'parse/dist/parse.min.js'
also don't work

Comment: Do *not* just open new questions that are [about the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77310488/546730). You can edit existing questions to add more details if necessary.